# If 2 cells match then make another 2 cells match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, search-indexing

I want to generate a special excel formula. My wish is to find out the last working day of each week. Thus, the formula is designed to analyze consecutive dates and find all Fridays, or, if there is no Friday for a given week, the last working day in the same week before Friday. The Friday or the nearest working day of a given week before Friday is marked with the symbol 1, other dates this week without the symbol ("") or a blank cell. See the attached screenshot for prepared results column. Note that sometimes there are several rows with the same date (red dates) and actually this is the problem which faced me.
So, the job result is an excel formula to mark such days with symbol 1.
[Screen-shot for what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vT3n.png)

Comment: You formula should ,, `=IF((WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(A2))>=1,1,"")` in `C2`,, get correct sequence,, you are getting correct result coz in `C24`, formula gets `ZERO` since `C23` &`C24` has similar Week number !!

Answer (score 0):

actually it's done
and I used this formula,

=IF(A2="","",IF(WEEKNUM(A2)<>WEEKNUM(A1),1,IF(A2=A1,C1,"")))

Thanks a lot